# xml catalogue help

Tags: xml

need help on an xml task, im new to xml. the task is to build a xml catalogue which has 4 genres of music with two examples know i have manged to make that but im having difficulty write the code for the xsl stylesheet

Comment: some of the code is not showing can some one check it
its from "ive started the code of as much as i know:" after this line the code is not showing

Comment: the code isnt show properly can somone fix it plz

Comment: use the 110 button to highlight code :-)

Comment: You need to post your current code to get more help. Note also that your namespace is a very old one, use:
`<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
     xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to do your homework but I can recommend a very good tutorial resource:
http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Books/Book1/index.html
which gives many examples of simple XSLT in action.

You could iterate (xsl:for-each) over all the `rock` children and then select each child in sequence and create whatever output XML you want (you will need to design this anyway)

Comment: ive managed to get it working using the website but only one of the rock shows ive still got 3 more genres and 7 more example how do i show them and i didnt understand (xsl:each)

Answer (score 2):

W3Schools has some good resources as well.
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

Here is a spec on XML Catalogs:
http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/spec-2001-08-06.html

One thing to keep in mind while writing XSL is that you are dealing with sets.  Anytime you use a select attribute it returns a set of nodes, even if it is a set of 1.

Look into xsl:element and xsl:attribute for creating new elements and attributes.

Comment: Christ, I can't stand that w3schools site, do you really like it?

Comment: They have a lot of really good information.  I have used it many times.